# Memory allocation error on Google cloud platform VM Instance for Keras Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy my trained model on GCP VM Instance. It is around 94mb in size. The code worked perfectly on my local machine. I was able to start the flask server,send an image through cURL call and get the result also.
But on GCP, whenever i try to load my model, I get this error `allocation of 52953088 exceeds 10% of system memory` and the process gets killed.

The same model loads safely and runs in my local machine. 
Should I increase the memory of the VM instance or is there any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the error by creating a new instance with more memory. Increasing the memory from micro(0.6gb apprx) to small(1.7gb) resolved the error.